# getting a python function of functionType for a nested function with recursion

Tags: python

I am trying to do unit testing for nested functions (function inside a function), I am using code("nested" is function name) from below link which would supply closures and returns a valid function that is callable from tests. It works for simple functions. I am trying to make it work for recursive functions.

As an example: 
I am trying to get a valid function for "innerfunction" which has an entry in co_freevars as "innerfunction".

I want to get a function (FunctionType I believe) for "innerfunction" as a callable. To get this I need to call FunctionType with a tuple with a FunctionType for "innerfunction". This becomes a recursive "dependency".  How can I resolve this dependency for parameters to be sent for "closures"

Function for

```
def toplevelfunction():
    def innerfunction(a):
        print ('val of a is ', a)
        if a > 0:
            innerfunction(a -1)
    innerfunction(10)
```

Original code that I am using:

```
def freeVar(val):
  def nested():
    return val
  return nested.__closure__[0]

codeAttribute = '__code__' if sys.version_info[0] == 3 else 'func_code'

def nested(outer, innerName, **freeVars):
  if isinstance(outer, (types.FunctionType, types.MethodType)):
    outer = outer.__getattribute__(codeAttribute)
  for const in outer.co_consts:
    if isinstance(const, types.CodeType) and const.co_name == innerName:
      return types.FunctionType(const, globals(), None, None, tuple(
          freeVar(freeVars[name]) for name in const.co_freevars))
```

https://code.activestate.com/recipes/580716-unit-testing-nested-functions/

How to add support for closures so below works:

func = nested(toplevelfunction, 'innerfunction')

func(5)

would return error need a closure of length 1.
Adding a closure referring to "const" shows up that it is of CodeType and not FunctionType. 
Adding a closure value to refer itself seems tricky after reading through the documentation.

I do find innerfunction as:

```
 {code} <code object innerfunction at 0x104b9bc00, file "/<filedirectory>/handle_results.py", line 44>
 co_argcount = {int} 1
 co_cellvars = {tuple} <class 'tuple'>: ()
 co_code = {bytes} b"t\x00\x00d\x01\x00|\x00\x00\x83\x02\x00\x01|\x00\x00d\x02\x00k\x04\x00r'\x00\x88\x00\x00|\x00\x00d\x03\x00\x18\x83\x01\x00\x01d\x00\x00S"
 co_consts = {tuple} <class 'tuple'>: (None, 'val of a is ', 0, 1)
 co_filename = {str} '/<fildirectory>/handle_results.py'
 co_firstlineno = {int} 44
 co_flags = {int} 19
 co_freevars = {tuple} <class 'tuple'>: ('innerfunction ',)
 co_kwonlyargcount = {int} 0
 co_lnotab = {bytes} b'\x00\x01\r\x01\x0c\x01'
 co_name = {str} 'innerfunction '
 co_names = {tuple} <class 'tuple'>: ('print',)
 co_nlocals = {int} 1
 co_stacksize = {int} 3
 co_varnames = {tuple} <class 'tuple'>: ('a',)
```

Comment: At the very least, you are missing the return statement that causes `toplevelfunction` to return the inner function, rather than returning `None` and discarding the function it creates.

Comment: can you elaborate? I edited above to specify how I am using "nested" from tests.

Comment: `toplevelfunction` doesn't do anything useful. You don't have an explicit `return` statement, so it implicitly returns `None`. No references to `innerfunction` exist after `toplevelfunction` exits. (Even if you did add `return innerfunction` to `toplevelfunction`, it's not a very interesting closure, because there are no other local variables in `toplevelfunction` for it to close over.)

Comment: Edited toplevelfunction. My function is a lot complicated and tried to simplify the fucntion. I can see that there are co_freevars with the function name itself. Trying to see how I can get out of this situation.

Comment: `innerfunction` in your edit *still* is not a closure, because `toplevelfunction` does not return it. It's just a function defined and used in the scope  of `top levelfunction`.

Comment: I have edited it to show how innerfunction shows up as the CodeType and its corresponding values.
The way I say it as closure is 
func = nested(toplevelfunction, 'innerfunction')
the closure is generated in:
tuple(
          freeVar(freeVars[name]) for name in const.co_freevars))

Comment: does it make sense now? I removed the wide usage of word "closure"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for hinting me on this limitation on my ActiveState recipe you linked to in your question!

You tried to unit test a local recursive function; my minimal example for this looks like this:

```
def f(x):
  def fac(n):
    return fac(n-1) * n if n > 1 else 1
  print "Faculty of", x, "is", fac(x)
```

So in a unit test you want to test the inner function `fac()`.  Simply applying my recipe leads to this error:

```
nestedFac = nested(f, 'fac')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in nested
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in <genexpr>
KeyError: 'fac'
```

This is because `fac` is an identifier used within the inner function, and you *must* specify the value of *each* identifier used within the inner function.  Callable identifiers are no exception:

```
nestedFac = nested(f, 'fac', fac=None)
```

This sets `fac` to the value `None` and the call to `nested` does not fail anymore.

Unfortunately, the resulting function will try to call `None(...)` when you call it:

```
nestedFac(5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in fac
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

You would need to pass the function itself as the value for `fac` to avoid this.  Unfortunately, you do not have it yet when you call `nested()`.  A repeated wrapping could be done like this:

```
nestedFac = nested(f, 'fac', fac=None)
nestedFac = nested(f, 'fac', fac=nestedFac)
nestedFac = nested(f, 'fac', fac=nestedFac)
nestedFac = nested(f, 'fac', fac=nestedFac)
```

This would limit your recursion depth to the number of wraps you applied:

```
nestedFac(2)
2
nestedFac(3)
6
nestedFac(4)
24
nestedFac(5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in fac
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in fac
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in fac
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in fac
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

To avoid this, you can pass a local function as proxy:

```
def q(*args, **kwargs):
  return nestedFac(*args, **kwargs)
nestedFac = nested(f, 'fac', fac=q)
```

Or as a `lambda`:

```
nestedFac = nested(f, 'fac', fac=lambda *args, **kwargs:
    nestedFac(*args, **kwargs))
```

Or for the special case of just one parameter:

```
nestedFac = nested(f, 'fac', fac=lambda n: nestedFac(n))
```

An extension to the `nested()` recipe which does this automatically would be the better approach, though.  Feel free to fork the recipe and add this aspect!  :-)